# Trying to plot the results of GSEA in python

Tags: python, gsea, pandas, gene-ontology, go

I'm having some major chaos with the output table generated and then passing that to my plot function. New to this (1st time), could somebody review this piece of code and suggest some corrections. I saved the output of a data frame as a txt file and it does not look good at all. The numbers and columns are there, but they follow some sort of strange wa, like a staircase.

```
# Create DataFrame from significant results
df_go = pd.DataFrame(
    [(
        r.GO,
        r.goterm.name,
        r.goterm.namespace,
        r.p_uncorrected,
        len(r.study_items),  # Number of study genes
        GO_items.count(r.GO),
        ', '.join([rev_mapper[y] for y in r.study_items])  # Concatenate study genes into a single string
    ) for r in goea_results_sig],
    columns=['GO', 'term', 'p', 'n_genes', 'n_study', 'n_go', 'study_genes']
)

print(df_go)
# Save DataFrame to a text file (CSV format)
df_go.to_csv('df_go_results.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
```

I can provide more code, because when I tried to commit and push from IDE onto github I got the following message.

`Successfully created project 'GSEAplots' on GitHub, but initial commit failed: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check) corrupt loose object 'a87848b96903648398f723df040fd0be540a025d' unable to read a87848b96903648398f723df040fd0be540a025d`

No idea why or what ? Git does not seem to interact with PyCharm and/ or Github really well ?

The plots code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(6,4),dpi=300)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 18
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Helvetica"


plt.scatter(df_p['Z'],-np.log10(df_p['P(sgRNAs)']),s=18,color='grey',alpha=0.3,linewidths=0.3,edgecolors='grey')


label_ls1 = list(df_up['Gene'])

df_show1 = df_p.loc[label_ls1,:]
lfc_ls1 = list(df_show1['Z']); p_ls1 = list(-np.log10(df_show1['P(sgRNAs)']))

plt.scatter(lfc_ls1,p_ls1,s=20,color='red',linewidths=0.5,edgecolors='grey')

for i, txt in enumerate(label_ls1[-4:]):
    plt.annotate(txt, (lfc_ls1[-4:][i]+0.03, p_ls1[-4:][i]-0.08),fontsize=8)
    
label_ls2 = list(df_down['Gene'])

df_show2 = df_p.loc[label_ls2,:]
lfc_ls2 = list(df_show2['Z']); p_ls2 = list(-np.log10(df_show2['P(sgRNAs)']))

plt.scatter(lfc_ls2,p_ls2,s=20,color='blue',linewidths=0.5,edgecolors='grey')

for i, txt in enumerate(label_ls2[1:5]):
    plt.annotate(txt, (lfc_ls2[1:5][i]+0.03, p_ls2[1:5][i]-0.08),fontsize=8)

plt.axhline(y=1.3, linestyle='--', color='lightgray') 
plt.axvline(x=-2, linestyle='--', color='lightgray') 
plt.axvline(x=2, linestyle='--', color='lightgray') 

plt.xlabel('Differential score (PRMT5/DMSO)')
plt.ylabel('-log10(p-value)')


#plt.savefig('DifferentialEssential_volcanoplot.png',dpi=300,facecolor='white')
plt.show()
```

Data frame that I am trying to plot has the following structure :

```
             total_samples  occurrence_total  occurrence_CRSsNP  \
```

ENSG00000100592             15                15                  8
ENSG00000101336             15                14                  8
ENSG00000134285             15                15                  8

```
             occurrence_CTL  sparsity  rlog_av_CTL  rlog_av_CRSsNP  \
```

ENSG00000100592               7  0.099193    11.709476       11.413235
ENSG00000101336               6  0.322330     4.084709        6.179892
ENSG00000134285               7  0.098323     9.169283        9.595925

```
            rlog_Regulation  vst_av_CTL  vst_av_CRSsNP vst_Regulation  \
```

ENSG00000100592             CTL   11.790292      11.367062            CTL
ENSG00000101336          CRSsNP    4.909465       7.051789         CRSsNP
ENSG00000134285          CRSsNP    9.142557       9.734598         CRSsNP

```
              raw_av_CTL  raw_av_CRSsNP Raw_Regulation structural_zero  \
```

ENSG00000100592  3973.285714       2428.500            CTL              No
ENSG00000101336    10.285714        119.750         CRSsNP              No
ENSG00000134285   602.857143        761.625         CRSsNP              No

```
             DESeq2Norm_av_CTL  DESeq2Norm_av_CRSsNP DESeq_Regulation  \
```

ENSG00000100592        3526.244455           2614.486202              CTL
ENSG00000101336           9.293777            131.796045           CRSsNP
ENSG00000134285         535.929110            828.762618           CRSsNP

```
                baseMean  log2FoldChange     lfcSE      stat  \
```

ENSG00000100592  3039.973387       -0.431423  0.076683 -5.626030
ENSG00000101336    74.628320        3.828859  0.605862  6.319689
ENSG00000134285   692.106981        0.628415  0.105894  5.934376

```
             pvalue_DESEq2  padj_DESEq2        pvalue      padj  \
```

ENSG00000100592   1.844041e-08     0.000120  3.694635e-06  0.038127
ENSG00000101336   2.620902e-10     0.000005  2.009572e-07  0.006221
ENSG00000134285   2.949646e-09     0.000029  1.052822e-06  0.016297

```
             errorBarUp  errorBarLow Final_Regulation external_gene_name
```

ENSG00000100592   -0.354739    -0.508106              CTL              DAAM1
ENSG00000101336    4.434721     3.222997           CRSsNP                HCK
ENSG00000134285    0.734309     0.522521           CRSsNP             FKBP11

Comment: Hi @aleksk31, welcome. It’s quite hard to answer your question as there in fact multiple questions there, and not enough context. Try and think how to break down your problem into smaller parts. If you are having GitHub or IDE issues open a new question on the main stack exchange. I suggest editing your question down to just your first immediate question, which is about saving a pandas dataframe. When you edit, tell us where the variable goea_results_sig comes from and why the resulting csv isn’t what you expect (we don’t know what you mean by staircase)